# How can I use flex to layout in css? (2 <section> in 1 row)?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `<section>`:

```
<header>

</header>
<section class="left">
</section>
```

```
<section class="right">
</section>
```

There is no tag that covers these 2 sections And Can not change or add to HTML . Now i want to use `flex` to layout this pages like:
|`left`|`right`|. Now I want layout header with 100% width , .left 30% and right 70%. Can you give me some ideas to fix this, thanks all

Comment: can you add a container around the two sections?

Comment: you should wrap them before

Answer (score 1):

the "proper" way would be to add a container around your two sections.  If all you have on the page are these sections you can apply display:flex to the body tag

```css
body{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-evenly;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
header,footer{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section class="left">left
</section>
<section class="right">right
</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Sorry about my code above. I forgot add `header` to `body`. If i use `display:flex` in `body` it will make `header` and `footer` same row with `section`

Comment: snippet revised to have header and footer displayed above and below sections

Comment: I don't know why, but this code doesn't work as I expected. .left and .right are not on a single row

Comment: provide code or link to your page

Answer (score 0):

```
<main class="container">
 <section class="left"></section>
 <section class="right"></section>
</main>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

No need for left or right class.
And you need a container.

Comment: My problem is can not change html code. only use css and js to change layout

Comment: Try float:left / float:right, but you can't use flex without a container box.

Comment: oh, I know how use `float` to layout this page. But i try to practice with `display:flex` and i spent alot of time

Comment: You can't learn it without the proper HTML. CSS is not isolated from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `display: flex;` on parent `<div>`.
You can also use `flex-direction: row;` in the parent `<div>` if you want to specify it.

[This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) page has a great guide for using flex properties.

Comment: yep, I know how to use `display:flex` with parent element. But my problem is not parent elemnt around 2 `section` :(

Answer (score -3):

This should provide the layout you're looking for.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .flex-container > div {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>  
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: He don't want to use any container around the sections.

Comment: @VishalKamlapure But he has to!